# Ajaxify will_paginate in rails 3.1

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I am trying to ajaxify will_paginate result in rails 3.1. I have gone through the example of railscasts episode #174 but it is not working for rails 3.1.

Is there a simple way to ajaxify will_paginate result in rails3.1?

Here is index.js.erb code for loading the user partial (this file is in app/views/users folder)
     `$('#test').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@users)) %>"`);

Here is my pagination.js code (this file is in app/assets/javascripts)

```
  $(function() {
  $(".users a").live("click", function() {
    $.get(this.href, null, null, "script");
    return false;
  });
  });
```

I am using will_paginate both the files are getting loaded and I have tested for it.

Any help on where I am making the mistake?

Thanks,

Comment: What doesn't work? What have you tried?

Comment: @DaveNewton I have edited the post with the code. Although my javascript file is loading but I am not able to see the ajaxified result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace the line in **pagination.js**:

`$(".users a").live("click", function() {`

with

`$(".pagination a").live("click", function() {`

Then just make sure your **index.js.erb** is named correctly. For example, if you're using pagination inside the view **show.html.erb**, your script has to be named **show.js.erb**